# Dynamically created form won't call controller

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, model-view-controller

I've been working on a website and I want user to be able to submit adresses. 
I thought I'd be fancy and when you haven't added an adress, present a button that will dynamically create a form for you to submit one.
It all seems fine, but when I click the submit button, the page refreshes, but my controller function doesn't get called. I've tried setting a breakpoint to validate this.

```
Controller function:

    public void AddAdress(string adressname, string streetname, string     streetnmbr, string zipcode, string country)
    {
//I breakpoint here//
        string check = adressname;
    }

Js function that gets called when u press add adress button:
function AddAdress()
{
    var noadressdiv = document.getElementById("noadress");
    divlocation = noadressdiv.getBoundingClientRect();

    noadressdiv.remove();

    CreateElements();

    var parentdiv = document.getElementById("parent");

    parentdiv.appendChild(adressdiv);
}

the CreateElements() function (this is a big one sorry)

    adressdiv = document.createElement("div");
    adressdiv.style.position = divlocation;
    adressdiv.setAttribute("justify-content", "flex");

    adressform = document.createElement("form");
    adressform.setAttribute("asp-controller", "User");
    adressform.setAttribute("asp-action", "AddAdress");
    adressform.method = "post";

 //I create all the input elements here//

    btnsubmit = document.createElement("button");
    btnsubmit.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    btnsubmit.setAttribute("id", "submit");
    btnsubmit.setAttribute("class", "btn-submit");
    btnsubmit.style.width = "70%";
    btnsubmit.innerHTML = "submit adress!";

    adressdiv.appendChild(adressform);
    adressform.appendChild(adressnameinput);
    adressform.appendChild(adressstreetinput);
    adressform.appendChild(adressnmbrinput);
    adressform.appendChild(adresszipinput);
    adressform.appendChild(adresscountryinput);
    adressform.appendChild(btnsubmit);
}
```

I wished the form would call the controller method, but it doesn't appear so. Anyone care to venture why?

Comment: Perhaps because `adressdiv` is unknown to the `AddAddress()` function? Without the full scope of the JavaScript code that's a best guess.

Comment: I don't think so, I declare all those variables globally

Comment: Here to help, but please don't expect us to gleen the wisdom of your code through our imagination. Please post your full code here so we can provide the help you need.

Comment: It mean it's not much more than this wrapped in  a script tag with some declarations at the top... I'm sorry it's not enough for you to make sense of :(